# How can I get BerkeleyDB for ActivePerl 5.10?

Tags: perl, winapi, module, berkeley-db, activeperl

I'm trying to find out where a BerkeleyDB PPM is for ActivePerl 5.10. Anyone have a clue where to find this, or how to build it?

I had found a lead [here](http://trouchelle.com/perl/ppmrepview.pl?l=berkeleydb&v=10). They claim BerkeleyDB 0.33 had built ok for Perl 5.10. They provide a link to the PPM, but not to the supporting zip file. So I got around it, manually getting [the ppm](http://trouchelle.com/ppm10/MSWin32-x86-multi-thread-5.10/BerkeleyDB.ppm) and [the zip](http://trouchelle.com/ppm10/BerkeleyDB-0.33.zip) and running ppm install on the ppm file. That didn't work because the dll provided in the zip can't be loaded.

It seems like the only thing to do is to get the BerkeleyDB code from Oracle, compile it for Win32 with visual studio (the provided MSI uses Cygwin tools), modify the tarball from CPAN and build the ppm myself.

Comment: I grabbed the Oracle source for building the Berkeley DB library and then grabbed BerkeleyDB-0.36. I modified the config.in properties correctly. The Oracle library built just fine. The Perl mod did not.

Also, using Visual C++, NOT Cygwin (what Oracle uses for their perl distro).

Comment: FYI, I was migrating an existing BDB app. Workaround = SQLite. Each BDB file = 1 Table of 2 Columns (key,value). Migrate each db_put and db_get to SQL Insert and Selects, respectfully.

Comment: I was going to suggest SQLite as an alternative.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer: Use Sqlite.
The long answer, compile it and debug it yourself, contribute it to the community.

Answer (score 2):

Start ppm, go to Edit -> Preferences -> repositories and add the ["trouchelle" repository](http://trouchelle.com/perl/ppmrepview.pl). They have a BerkelyDB package for ActiveState Perl 5.10.

Comment: I think I tried that a good while ago. I just noticed that v .33 is the only version that did not fail during compile. I'll have to see if that's a version that's compatible with my app.

Comment: The bummer is that this doesn't work. See http://community.activestate.com/forum/berkeleydb-perl10-ppm.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into getting [Strawberry Perl](http://strawberryperl.com/)? It may not be appropriate for your purposes, but a large part of the reason for its creation is the much better (although not perfect) support for CPAN modules, as opposed to requiring the PPM repositories to be kept up to date.

Comment: For the rectord, ActivePerl has always had the same CPAN shell, and now fetches the auxiliary build tools as needed (MinGW). 

Building BerkeleyDB-0.42 with Strawberry Perl fails at the same place as it does with ActivePerl.

Answer (score -2):

Doesn't DBD::DBM support BerkelyDB?